# Incorporating a Pre-Built App in an Android Automotive System Image

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

I'm trying to make an Android Automotive system image and want to include a native pre-built 3rd-party app ("foo.apk").  Is it possible to 'install' foo.apk in an AAOS image as a system app?  If so, would the correct place to put it be in system/app/foo, and to extract the native lib files in system/app/foo/x86_64?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.